# Filter how many dates out of the dates in range are equal to Today

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using a Google Sheets spreadsheet as a more flexible to-do list app alternative.

How would I create a filter for how many tasks are due **today** out of a range of `=DATE...` cells. I've tried using `=FILTER` and `=COUNT` formulas but have never been able to get it to work. How would I do this?

I need to filter how many dates out of the dates in `B2:B14` are `=TODAY()`.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried (add the complete formulas) directly in the question body and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Try this one:

`=counta(iferror(filter(B2:B, B2:B = today())))`

The benefit of this pattern is that you can easily add more conditions to the `filter()`.